# If we enforce SSO to Salesforce and it breaks how do we log in as an admin to fix?

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-authentication

We have Azure AD to Salesforce SSO. We don't want to allow the option for SSO users to log in directly.

If we enforce SSO to Salesforce and it breaks how do we log in as an admin to fix?

For example, if I am an admin, and SSO doesn't work and needs to be fixed, how do I log into Salesforce?

Comment: I look like this does answer my question. Thank you.